# Pytest Assertion Error Issue

Tags: python, pytest

Hi so I have a function here:

```
def cross_product(t1,t2):
    new = []

    #create new schema
    for category in t2[0]:
        t1[0].append(category)
    new.append(t1[0])
    #make table content
    if t1 != t2:
        for row in t1[1:]:
            step = 0
            for i in t2[1:]:
                new.append(row + i)

    if len(new) < 2:
        return None

    return new
```

which works as I wanted it to.  However, when I test it using this py.test function, I keep getting an assertion error if there is more than one assert statement in the function.  I've checked the code and there shouldn't be an assertion error at all...yet I can't seem to fix it. Anyone able to tell me what I can do to fix this?  I'm still in the beginner stages of learning python so keep it simple, if you can.

heres the test case:

```
 def test_cross_product_basic():
    """
    Test cross product operation with basic/generic inputs.
    """

    result_1 = [["Employee", "Department", "Department", "Head"],
            ["Smith", "sales", "production", "Mori"],
            ["Smith", "sales", "sales", "Brown"],
            ["Black", "production", "production", "Mori"],
            ["Black", "production", "sales", "Brown"],
            ["White", "production", "production", "Mori"],
            ["White", "production", "sales", "Brown"]]

    assert is_equal(result_1, cross_product(R1, R2))

    result_2 = [['Department', 'Head', 'Employee', 'Department'],
            ['production', 'Mori', 'Smith', 'sales'],
            ['production', 'Mori', 'Black', 'production'],
            ['production', 'Mori', 'White', 'production'],
            ['sales', 'Brown', 'Smith', 'sales'],
            ['sales', 'Brown', 'Black', 'production'],
            ['sales', 'Brown', 'White', 'production']]
    assert is_equal(result_2, cross_product(R2, R1))

    result_3 = [['Surname', 'FirstName', 'Age', 'Salary', 'Employee', 'Department'],
            ['Smith', 'Mary', 25, 2000, 'Smith', 'sales'],
            ['Smith', 'Mary', 25, 2000, 'Black', 'production'],
            ['Smith', 'Mary', 25, 2000, 'White', 'production'],
            ['Black', 'Lucy', 40, 3000, 'Smith', 'sales'],
            ['Black', 'Lucy', 40, 3000, 'Black', 'production'],
            ['Black', 'Lucy', 40, 3000, 'White', 'production'],
            ['Verdi', 'Nico', 36, 4500, 'Smith', 'sales'],
            ['Verdi', 'Nico', 36, 4500, 'Black', 'production'],
            ['Verdi', 'Nico', 36, 4500, 'White', 'production'],
            ['Smith', 'Mark', 40, 3900, 'Smith', 'sales'],
            ['Smith', 'Mark', 40, 3900, 'Black', 'production'],
            ['Smith', 'Mark', 40, 3900, 'White', 'production']]
    assert is_equal(result_3, cross_product(EMPLOYEES, R1))
```

and here's the lists Im using:

```
R1 = [["Employee", "Department"],
  ["Smith", "sales"],
  ["Black", "production"],
  ["White", "production"]]
EMPLOYEES = [["Surname", "FirstName", "Age", "Salary"],
         ["Smith", "Mary", 25, 2000],
         ["Black", "Lucy", 40, 3000],
         ["Verdi", "Nico", 36, 4500],
         ["Smith", "Mark", 40, 3900]]
R2 = [["Department", "Head"],
  ["production", "Mori"],
  ["sales", "Brown"]]
```

Apologies for any formatting issues, I'm not so good with SO's text editor

Comment: To use the editor, you can copy your code directly and then highlight it and click the icon the looks like `{}`.  That will indent your code correctly for the editor.

Comment: thanks but not what I was asking

Comment: I realize I wasn't answering your question (If I was answering your question, I would have posted an answer :-).  I just wanted to drop you a comment to hopefully help you learn how to use the site.

Comment: where has "is_equal" method come from?

Comment: Can you post the output of py.test, including the Assertion Error

Comment: Thanks mgilson! I hope I wasn't too snarky :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cross_product function modifies its arguments (for example, `t1[0].append(category)`).  Therefore after the first test is complete your test lists R1 and R2 are not at their original values, having been modified by the function.  Pass copies of the test lists instead.

Comment: hmm, I made two more variables that contain a slice of t1 and t2 and am still getting an error

Comment: You really should rewrite cross_product so it doesn't modify the arguments.  That's just asking for trouble.

Comment: Good advice, I did that but still had issues.  Turns out the way I learned copying didn't account for nested lists and that I had to roll my own deep copy function (doing this as part of an assignment and the prof said no modules). Called the deep copy on each table in cross product and managed to fix it.